# What are the 9 easter eggs?

Tags: pixel-people

I'm stumped at the "Easter Bunny" gene at the gene pool.  I've unlocked it twice now - and it has taken my utopium to do so, but it continues to stay locked.
How do you collect the 9 easter eggs that supposedly unlock this final gene?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Pixel People wiki,](http://pixelpeople.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs_Mission) the 9 eggs are located in the following locations:

> - Sheriff's Office - "Search" -  Click on the first two people who are Producers (Abhishek Radhakrishnan and Ivan Loo) and then click on last
>     person who is a Litterbug  (Esther Bunyee; looks like an Easter Bunny)
> - Fire Station
> - Museum
> - Park
> - Courthouse - "VIEW" - Click on the Mayor gene, Deputy gene, and Farmer gene (all found on page 1)
>
> Alternatively, players can bypass the mission for 50u, unlocking the
>   Easter Bunny gene without having to pay and/or unlock all the
>   requirements for the mission.